# Structure Monthly Archive - archive template

Tags: structure, listing

I have a listing channel of a news/blog page. I'm attempting to use the Structure Monthly Archive plugin to achieve this. Everything seems to be as it should, however I keep getting a 404 error when I attempt to access the monthly.

My structure is like this: 
mysite.com/resources/newscenter - this spits out a paginated list of all news/blogs articles

In the left column of this page I've got the Structure Monthly Archive plugin coded, the archive list shows - but when I go to click on the link [which looks like this: resources/newscenter/archives/2014/02] I'm getting the 404 error.

But I can go to: resources/newscenter/archives - where it displays the same list as the main newscenter page: resources/newscenter

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
"No need to rely on Channels to separate your entries"
```

This copy says to me the addon works on Structure Page entries, not with Structure Listing entries as your question suggests you are using.

Here is a screenshot from the [Structure Monthly Archives](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure-monthly-archives) Devot:ee page showing how the entries need to be setup for the addon to work.

[image]

Comment: Oh I wish you were right, but this is the first sentence on the Add-on's page: Creates a monthly archive list based on Structure Pages or Listings by passing an Entry ID. Given it says listing, it should work. I've tried it on another project thinking it could be a server issue as I've had problems on this server with other things [unfortunately it's not under my direct control] - and i did get a page to render, but some things were still amiss as I tried to punch it out in a hurry...

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep the news listing outside of Structure and build the archive as you would normally? You can still assign the channel to a Structure node but have a template group of /news and then /news/archive to do the usual breakdown of filters.

Comment: Thanks Steven, a friend turned me on to Zoo Triggers and it did the trick before I saw this. Thank you for chiming in!